# I forgot my Outlook ID used in BizSpark

Tags: outlook, bizspark

My company uses BizSpark and i had created an outlook mail to register there. But i can not remember that email address, our admin can see registered mails but we can only see my contact mail in there, not the microsoft account.

Is there a way to find the email name that I created for the bizspark account? I know its password but not the name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab all possible information you may have about your account: old passwords, details registered like credit cards, basically everything possible linked to the account and contact Microsoft Support on the phone, explain your issue and provide all possible details to the agent, for sure they have a way to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, gonna try it.

Comment: I worked for Microsoft providing Support for the Xbox and we had options for that, the most successful was the credit card. Try everything possible and let me know how it went. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't use any credit card with that account. In fact, i actually just created that account and logged in to BizSpark. Then i never used that account anymore. So i have no credit cards and old passwords. I don't know what to do, isn't there an option to see the registered microsoft account from our company's admin panel in the bizspark?

Comment: If you have multiple users on your BizSpark account you can provide them details about those users. If the account you are talking about is a user linked to your main BizSpark account then you can do it in the admin panel, by managing the users. 

If you never used it, and have no details there that can help a Microsoft agent find it in the system, the other option you have is making a list of possible emails or all emails you ever created and try to login with all of them, if you find the right one, even with the wrong password, you will notice it as the error message should be different.

Comment: Thank you dude, i'm starting to try it out. I will let you know about the results.

Comment: To double check it the email is being used, you can always try to recover the account with all possible emails, the messages coming on the screen are clearer and will give you a precious hint.
Don't discard any emails, sometimes we think that a specific email was never used for that, but who knows? It worth a try, and sometimes we get a good surprise.

Comment: Lol, I have just found the email by trying. Thank you anyway for the hints!